# haml to html conversion for ruby on Rails application?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I want to do Search Engine Optimization most effectively? the following HAML meta-tags are in my new ruby on rails application.is there any advantage if i convert this into HTML ?

```
- content_for :title,       @service ? @service.page_title : " - Legal Compliance"
- content_for :description, @service ? @service.meta_description : "Legal Compliance"
- content_for :keyword,     @service ? @service.meta_keywords : "Legal Compliance"
```

Comment: And I want a cookie! :) What have you tried so far && what is not working?

Comment: i want to import meta keywords from services database.want to convert the above codes to suitable to html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want ?

```html
<% content_for :title,       @service ? @service.page_title : " - Legal Compliance" %>
<% content_for :description, @service ? @service.meta_description : "Legal Compliance" %>
<% content_for :keyword,     @service ? @service.meta_keywords : "Legal Compliance" %>
```